#  Make lines of text have equal length

Tags: javascript, jquery

In centered `h1` elements, if the text falls on multiple lines, line breaks make the text look like this:

```
                This is a header that takes up two
                              lines

                This is a header that takes up three
                lines because it is really, really
                              long
```

Is there a way to manipulate these elements so that the length of the lines of text is roughly equal? Like this:

```
                       This is a header that
                        takes up two lines

                    This is a header that takes 
                     up three lines because it
                       is really, really long
```

The jQuery plugin [Widow Fix](http://matthewlein.com/widowfix/index.html) prevents single-word lines, but I'm looking for something that evens out *all* the lines in a multi-line element. Are there any jQuery plugins for this, or can you recommend a strategy?

Comment: You can use the css text-align: justify;

But I don't know a good solution for JavaScript.

Comment: Here's a word wrap function for JavaScript: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/wordwrap-for-javascript/

Comment: When you say "roughly-equal" are you basing this on a word-count, or a letter count? What about punctuation?

Comment: @Michael Paulukonis: I'm guessing letter count including punctuation.

Comment: I have started creating a jQuery plugin for this issue. I will continue working on it until somebody posts a valid answer. I have had this problem myself and this is the perfect opportunity to start working to a solution.

Comment: @Michael Paulukonis, I really mean actual width (since I'm not using a monospace font), but character count could be an adequate proxy. Avaq: awesome!

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty way to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/gD6aX/3/

Comment: @BrentAnderson that's great—you should post it as an answer. The only thing is all my font sizes and line heights are in `em`s--is there a way to convert between them or work around it?

Comment: Have you tried it?  I think it will still calculate correctly.  Fork the fiddle and add some of your own values.  I did't post it as an answer because something like this needs to be tested extensively and I don't have that much time :)

Comment: @BrentAnderson +1 for erring on the side of caution.  Change `header that takes` to `header WWW WWW WWW takes` and it pushes to 3 lines.  However, the fix here would be to make a bisection search for a width that is neither too narrow or wide.

Answer (score 5):

I would solve it using only strict JavaScript, going this way:

1. put a class named 'truncate' to h1 tags you want to break
2. configure the javascript code on your needs knowing that

MAXCOUNT: (integer) max chars counted per line

COUNT_SPACES: (boolean) white spaces must be counted?

COUNT_PUNCTUATION: (boolean) punctuation must be counted?

EXACT: (boolean) the last word must be cut?

BLOCKS_CLASS: (string) the className of the h1 to consider

I wrote the code very quickly so it must be better tested for bugs,
but it can be a starting point I think.

I'm not using jQuery in this code to keep the code light and to avoid dependencies.
I think I'm using all cross-browser commands (cannot test it I've got only linux now). However any correction for cross-browser compatibility task (included the use of jQUery if requested) might be easy.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        h1 {background-color: yellow;}
        #hiddenDiv {background-color: yellow; display: table-cell; visibility:hidden;}
    </style>
    <script>

        var MAXCOUNT            = 20;
        var COUNT_SPACES        = false;
        var EXACT               = false;
        var COUNT_PUNCTUATION   = true;
        var BLOCKS_CLASS        = 'truncate';

        window.onload = function () 
        {
            var hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');

            if (hidden == null)
            {
                hidden = document.createElement('div');
                hidden.id = 'hiddenDiv';
                document.body.appendChild(hidden);
            }

            var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName(BLOCKS_CLASS);     

            for (var i=0; i<blocks.length; i++)
            {
                var block           = blocks[i];
                var text            = block.innerHTML;
                var truncate        = '';
                var html_tag        = false;
                var special_char    = false;
                maxcount            = MAXCOUNT;
                for (var x=0; x<maxcount; x++)
                {
                    var previous_char = (x>0) ? text.charAt(x-1) : '';
                    var current_char = text.charAt(x);

                    // Closing HTML tags
                    if (current_char == '>' && html_tag)
                    {
                        html_tag = false;
                        maxcount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Closing special chars
                    if (current_char == ';' && special_char)
                    {
                        special_char = false;
                        maxcount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Jumping HTML tags
                    if (html_tag)
                    {
                        maxcount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Jumping special chars
                    if (special_char)
                    {
                        maxcount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Checking for HTML tags
                    if (current_char == '<')
                    {
                        var next = text.substring(x,text.indexOf('>')+1);
                        var regex = /(^<\w+[^>]*>$)/gi;
                        var matches = regex.exec(next); 
                        if (matches[0])
                        {
                            html_tag = true;
                            maxcount++;
                            continue;
                        }                       
                    }
                    // Checking for special chars
                    if (current_char == '&')
                    {
                        var next = text.substring(x,text.indexOf(';')+1);
                        var regex = /(^&#{0,1}[0-9a-z]+;$)/gi;
                        var matches = regex.exec(next);
                        if (matches[0])
                        {
                            special_char = true;
                            maxcount++;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }                   
                    // Shrink multiple white spaces into a single white space
                    if (current_char == ' ' && previous_char == ' ')
                    {
                        maxcount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Jump new lines
                    if (current_char.match(/\n/))
                    {
                        maxcount++;
                        continue;
                    }                   
                    if (current_char == ' ')
                    {
                        // End of the last word
                        if (x == maxcount-1 && !EXACT) { break; }
                        // Must I count white spaces?
                        if ( !COUNT_SPACES ) { maxcount++; }
                    }
                    // Must I count punctuation?
                    if (current_char.match(/\W/) && current_char != ' ' && !COUNT_PUNCTUATION)
                    {
                        maxcount++;
                    }
                    // Adding this char
                    truncate += current_char;
                    // Must I cut exactly?
                    if (!EXACT && x == maxcount-1) { maxcount++; }
                }

                hidden.innerHTML = '<h1><nobr>'+truncate+'</nobr></h1>';

                block.style.width = hidden.offsetWidth+"px";
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>


<body>

<center>
    <h1 class="truncate">
        This is a header that
        takes up two lines
    </h1>

    <br>

    <h1 class="truncate">
        This is a header that takes 
        up three lines because it
        is really, really long
    </h1>

    <br>

    <h1>
        This is a header pretty short
        or pretty long ... still undecided
        which in any case is not truncated!
    </h1>
</center>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/6rtdF/

Answer (score 1):

Late to this party, but here's my approach. I get the initial element height (any elements with the class `balance_lines`, in the code below), then incrementally shrink the width of the element. Once the height of the element changes, I've gone too far. The step before that should have lovely roughly-equal line lengths.

```
$('.balance_lines').each(function(){
    var currentHeight = $(this).height();
    var thisHeight = currentHeight;
    var currentWidth = $(this).width();
    var newWidth = currentWidth;
    // Try shrinking width until height changes
    while (thisHeight == currentHeight) {
        var testWidth = newWidth - 10;
        $(this).width(testWidth);
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight == currentHeight) {
            newWidth = testWidth;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $(this).width(newWidth);
});
```

You can see this code in action on the homepage at [apollopad.com](https://apollopad.com/).

Comment: Actually, this is really neat idea - clever thinking. I guess it is not upvoted because it wasn't explained well and nobody really bothered to understand. Thanks!

Comment: ... and it should be a faster solution also

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS Text 4 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-4/#valdef-text-wrap-balance) proposes `text-wrap: balance`, but I don't think any browser implements it yet.

In the meantime, you can use Adobe's jQuery plugin ([demo](http://webplatform.adobe.com/balance-text/demo/)): https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/balance-text