# Make half of the words go onto the next line if it can't all fit on one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a string of text, that is only over one line on large screens, but breaks onto two lines if on mobile.

I am wondering if it is possible to distribute the text **equally** between the two lines, only IF it breaks onto two lines. This means that it needs to make half the text go on a second line and half stay on the first line if it cant all fit on one line, whereas the default behaviour is to just put the words that can't fit on that line onto the second line.

The only possible way I can think to do this is to sub-divide the string up into two separate flex elements that wrap at a certain width, but I am wondering if there is a method which will do all of this for me without having to manually divide the string into two elements.

**Goal: make half of the words go onto the next line if it can't all fit on one.**

Comment: I'm sure there's a convoluted way to do this in JS. However a more simple approach may be to use CSS: `text-align: justify` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/

Comment: Is it like, you have a string that occupies 500 pixels width, than you get text container shrunk to 400px, and your text justifies into a) 2 lines 250px wide each; b) 2 lines 400px wide with spacing between words almost doubled? Won't that look weird from UX point of view?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov a) is the desired outcome. It will be text centered so it will look even

Comment: My string will be at least ten words - the specific breakpoint within the word is not the concern. I just want half the words to go onto a new line if it cant all fit on one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's not related to the desired outcome.

Comment: Detecting if the paragraph wraps at all to begin with is going to be very challenging.

Comment: My point was rather like is it ***'half of the words'*** or ***'half of the words width'***?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070160/make-lines-of-text-have-equal-length) answer your question?

Comment: @Sean now the OP has edited the question and commented with some clarity, it appears that you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by saying: there is no built-in solution in CSS for what you want to achieve. But there is a [Adobe jQuery plugin](https://github.com/adobe/balance-text) that will do the trick for you.

If you are not interested in the plugin, I'll give you another "manual split" option to consider:

You can replace the space characters you DON'T want to break with `&nbsp;`. This character is a "Non-breaking space", which means it looks exactly like a space, but it never breaks between lines. So at the point you WANT the text to break if necessary, you leave a normal space character. So you would have something like:

```html
This&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;long&nbsp;text&nbsp;that&nbsp;will break&nbsp;in&nbsp;half&nbsp;in&nbsp;small&nbsp;screens
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `</br>` for linebreak inside the text.
This one is a bit tricky, since we are mixing text and DOM nodes.

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</br> Morbi ac posuere ante. </br> Mauris quis facilisis tortor.</br> Donec blandit eleifend tincidunt. Nullam dictum ipsum vel nibh fringilla tincidunt.</br>Sed pellentesque ultricies urna, ac finibus ipsum varius in.
</p>
```

Doing it in javascript means we can set exactly where the text breaks.
**Beware, bad practice and risk of code injection if we are inserting any form of user input. Make sure to have validation**

```
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac posuere ante.'
var newString
var index = 20

// Insert at at specific length points, 20 in this case
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
  // Break if not matching index
  if(i % index !== 0)
    continue;
  newString += text.slice(i, i+index) + "</br>"
}

CHILD_NODE.innerhtml = newString
WHATEVER_TARGET_NODE.append(CHILD_NODE)
```

Comment: This is interesting, however if you are having to choose where to break the text manually then it is probably better to just use two separate flex elements which will be cleaner and CSS only.

Comment: @DevOverflow I agree. But since OP didn't provide any html I went with the assumption of only using a single string, so more of a concept suggestion.

One would also be required to apply logic of wherein the breaks/paragraphs are done, since you probably don't want a word to be split up.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do this using CSS,

> text-align-last: justify; /*this is the key*/

```
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
```

this will work like full justify and will fill the line complete even with 2 words.
i think that is what you wanted

Comment: This is about alignment, whereas I want the words to break so that half of the words go onto the new line if it cant all fit onto one